# jquery - dynamically fill fields with json based on property name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

1. asp.net mvc model object is being fetched by ajax call - $.ajax(....
2. form has fields with IDs exactly to matching properties on returned json object (created by `Html.TextBox("NAME", Model.Order.NAME)` )

How to automatically populate fields(inputs) with corresponding json object properties ?
Manually would be like `$("#NAME).val(json.NAME)` so how to make this dynamic?
Is there some kind of reflections (like System.Reflection in c#) for javascript/jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$("#formId input").each(function(){
   $(this).val(json[$(this).attr("id")]);
});
```

... which iterates over all the form inputs, and looks for a JSON entry with the inputs ID.

The thing to note here is that you can retrieve `json.NAME` via `json["NAME"]`.